# notepad++ have weird number line?

Tags: notepad++

Hi can someone tell me how to change the line number notepad++ to normal number line? thanks

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: These numbers look hexadecimal. By "normal" you mean "decimal"? Some people would say hexadecimal notation is as normal as decimal. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have Notepad++ Plugin `CustomLineNumbers` enabled.

[image: notepad++ custom line numbers plugin]

[image: npp plugin customlinenumber]

**Disable it or Uncheck** setting that shows it as Hexadecimal numbers. And you should have a regular line numbers.

[image: hexadecimal line numbers]

Comment: thanks! LOL I must be forgot where to disable this., thanks!!!